# Check if product category page is not empty in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on null in...

when category/shop/archive page is empty or has not products:

```
function display_loop_item_stock_notice() {
    global $product;

    // For active product price: Free shipping || NO Free shipping
    $text = $product->get_price() >= 500 ? '<span>Free shipping</span>' : '<span>Free shipping from 500 €</span>';

    // In stock
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) { 
        $text = '<span>In stock</span>' . ' <span class="free-shipping">' . $text . '</span>';
    } 
    // Out of stock
    else {
        $text = '<span><strong>' . get_field( 'date_of_availability' ) . '</strong></span>' . '<span class="free-shipping">' . $text . '</span>';
        echo '<div class="remaining text-center">' . $text . '</div>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_loop_item_stock_notice', 90 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if $product is null.

```
...
global $product;

if (is_null($product)) {
  return;
}
```